# Show attributes in the layer panel

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table

I've got an layer with different type of streets (feature class in attribute table). Now I want to all the different types to show up in the layer panel, like it is in the picture (sorry for the bad quality...).

How can I get this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `categorized` style? https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html